# Get last type of executed query in sqlite3

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I'm using the sqlite3 C API and would like to know if it's possible to know the type of the last executed statement (select/update/insert/delete).

The ugly alternative is to keep track of the last statement and process it myself to figure out which kind it is.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know this is not supported in the C api. You have two options: either you modify the C API to include support for what you're asking or wrap the select/update/insert/delete commands with your own implementation that keeps track of them. I don't think it's that ugly (;

Comment: What do you need this information for?

Comment: I'm using sqlite in memory dbs to provide testing mocks for classes that talk to actual disk dbs. I have a wrapper around sqlite3 that implements my DB interface. This interface provides a common execute method but then allows to query the num of inserted/updated/deleted columns separately, it can tell the difference.